# Можно ли иметь один и тот же список в нескольких сортированных вариантах?

Tags: python

Имеется такой список:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Можно ли сделать на него ссылку отсортировать, например так:

```
l2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

И при изменении элемента в одном из массивов менялся элемент и в другом. Например

```
l2[0] = 1
print(l2) # 1, 4, 3, 2, 1
print(l1) # 1, 2, 3, 4, 1
```

Зачем мне это? Имеется массив координат. С разных сторон имеются точки, несколько штук. И нужно от массива отщипывать по ближайшей координате от этих точек, но координаты не должны повторяться.

Comment: явно указывать для обоих списков не вариант? изменение по индексу

Comment: Да, вариант, точек будет 4, 4 списка изменять придется, но может есть элегантный способ

Comment: Есть вариант, пересортировывать постоянно один и тот же массив относительно точек

Comment: может тогда в функцию засунуть обработку всех списков? подавать на вход индекс и значение, и список списков, чтобы пробегаться по всем и менять. Может опишите более детально задачу, и сначала над алгоритмом подумаем?

Comment: Заведите один список со значениями и два списка с индексами. Индексы отсортируйте по значениям. Меняйте основной список, обращайтесь к нему через индексы.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте дам такой вариант

```py
x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
x2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
t = x1, x2

for i in t:   
  i[0] = 10
```

Переменная `t` - кортеж. Можно сделать именнованым для нескольких координат

```py
x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
x2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y2 = [5,4,3,2,1]

t = x1, x2


from collections import namedtuple

Coordinate = namedtuple("Coordinate", ["x1", "x2", "y1", "y2"])
C = Coordinate(x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

В этом случае уже можно будет обращаться вот так

```py
>>> C._asdict()
{'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'x2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'y1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
```

или вот так

```py
>>> C.x1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

и вносить изменения

**UPD**

Добавлю реализацию предложенную @Stanislav Volodarsky

```py
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
indx_x1 = sorted(range(len(values)), key=lambda k: values[k])
indx_x2 = indx_x1[::-1]
values[0] = 30

x1 = [values[i] for i in indx_x1]
x2 = [values[i] for i in indx_x2]

# OUT
# x1 = [30, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# x2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 30]
```